# Complex NSPredicate traversing multiple Entities and relationship types

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, key-value-observing

I'm having a tough time solving this predicate issue since the database structure is a bit complex. I have the following database structure, or at least what is of concern for this question:

PUBLISHER<< --- >>PUBLICIST<<--BOOK<<--->AUTHOR<<-->>AGENTS

I tried the following predicate that I have used when I traversed relationships in the past, but not to this degree. I should mention that I have an NSArray with agent names that I want to query against the database to determine a list of publishing houses the agent works with:

```
NSArray *agentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Dan, Hunter, Sloan, Jackson];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Publisher" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor
             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"publisherName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] ];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY pubHouse.publicist.assignedBook.authorRep.agentName IN %@", [agentNames valueForKey:@"agentName"]];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

    NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

When I run the previous predicate I get the following warning:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : ANY pubHouse.publicist.assignedBook.authorRep.agentName IN
```

I believe the predicate breaks when I travel the Book Entity relationship to the Author Entity and then onto the Agent Entity. At this point suggestions would help. Thanks

Comment: What are the variables in your NSArray agentNames? NSManagedObject subclasses? Dictionaries?

Comment: Are all the relationships between your entities just regular old relationships, or is anything "special" about them? Also, `authorRep.agentName` looks a bit curious. Is `agentName` really the name of your AUTHOR<<-->>AGENTS relationship? Or did you mean something like `authorRep.agent.agentName`?

Comment: It's an array of Agent objects that are passed from a previous view controller where the user would select which agents they want to query. I have used this approach previously with success. I displayed the example array in this question in such a way to help the good samaritans out there understand what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for putting in the effort.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard. It's just poorly phrased on my part. I was asked to mask the actual entity names and this was the best I could come up with. "authorRep" would be the relationship name and "agentName" would be an NSString attribute of the Agent Entity. Sorry if it's a bit obtuse.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you ditch the `valueForKey:` and use `IN %@.agentName` instead? I'm not actually sure if that's even supported, and if it is it may not work anyway because your problem is likely in another part of the predicate. I'm just curious ;)

Comment: Another thought: What if you ditch the sort? It's possible that sort method isn't supported by the SQL generator. Though I'd expect to see a slightly different error in that case.

Comment: And lastly, are any of these properties transient properties? For example, `agentName`? Those aren't supported in fetches.

Comment: I tried the IN %@.agentName and it did not work. Also, there are no transient properties. I think I read that the left hand operator in the IN statement must appear in the right hand (Array) collection. I would think that this situation would be the case, but I must be missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the predicate parser has no clue what set `ANY` should be applied to.

With this data model:

```
PUBLISHER<< --- >>PUBLICIST<<-->BOOK<<--->AUTHOR<<-->>AGENTS
```

… your keypath:

```
pubHouse.publicist.assignedBook.authorRep.agentName
```

… in terms of objects and set of the relationship looks something like:

```
object.set.object.object.set
```

So, that is two sets that the `ANY` could apply to.

You could try to build a subquery to handle the predicate but if you have to transverse that many relationships, your fetch will involve a big chunk of your data and will be very, very slow (assuming you get it work in the first place.)

Usually when you end up with a convoluted predicate like this it indicates that you are approaching the problem from the wrong end. In this case, it would be easier to start with a simple predicate like:

```
NSArray *agentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Dan, Hunter, Sloan, Jackson];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Agent" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"agentName IN %@", agentNames];
```

Then you would walk the relationship keypath of:

```
authors.books.publicist.publishers
```

… to find all the related publishers.

I think that you will have trouble no matter what you do because having more than one to-many-to-many relationship e.g.

```
PUBLISHER<<--->>PUBLICIST
```

… increases the complexity of predicates and relationship walks exponentially. Usually, in such a case, you may need an additional entity to more thoroughly model one of the relationships. That usually reduces the complexity of the data model itself which simplifies fetches and walks.

Comment: You are right. I tried to find a decent workaround, but I had to iron out some relationships and create Entities that reduced the number of many to many relationships in order to walk through the relationship. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `NSArray` has a problem with `valueForKey:`. I have seen a solution that uses NSCompoundPredicate adding the array items in a loop.

BTW, in your chain of multiple relationships, aren't you **missing your authors**?

Comment: `valueForKey:` works on `NSArray`. It constructs a new array composed of the results of calling `valueForKey:` with the given key on every element of the array (replacing nil values with `NSNull`).

Comment: @KevinBallard Please see my addition above.

Comment: Any problems from `[agentNames valueForKey:@"agentName"]` would produce a completely different error.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the `IN` clause of your predicate string in parentheses:

```
@"ANY (pubHouse.publicist.assignedBook.authorRep.agentName IN %@)"
```

Would be glad to know if it works.